# Making env.user and env.key_filename global in Python Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I have several Fabric tasks that I want to run as user `some-other-user`. For example,

install.py -

```
def install_vim_on_host():
    cmd = 'apt get install vim'
    result = sudo(cmd, user=env.user)
```

`install_vim_on_host` gets called from a function which uses Fabric's execute() method -

```
def install_package(host_list):
    ...
    execute(install_vim_on_host, hosts=host_list)
```

I want to be able to use `env.user` in other python modules as well. I have the private key of `some-other-user` in my home directory so I put the following code at the beginning of the first module that gets loaded in all other modules -

```
# setup some-other-user's identity
env.user = 'some-other-user'
cmd = 'echo $HOME'
with hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr') :
    home_dir = local(cmd, capture=True)
env.key_filename = '%s/.ssh/some_other_user_rsa.pk' %(home_dir)
if not os.path.exists(env.key_filename):
    print 'private key of user some-other-user is not found'
    sys.exit()
```

This seems to be working fine, but I want to put the above setup code in a function rather than leaving it as is in one of my modules. Is there any way to achieve this such that env.user and env.key_filename is made global and can be accessed from any function in any module?

Answer (score 0):

You could set all this in your `$HOME/.ssh/config` for specific hosts for this other user, and tell fabric to honor the ssh config with a global `env.use_ssh_config = True`.

`$HOME/.ssh/config`

```
Host remote_host_type*
    User some-other-user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/some_other_user_rsa.pk
```

If you didn't want this globally set, you can make a different ssh_config file and have fabric point there as well, using the `--ssh-config-path=PATH`

Other options would likely involve having the function run globally and/or just using the knowledge of `__name__` to determine if the file was run or imported to know when to call the function you're purposing.